# How to begin working with GwtQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, gquery, gwtquery

I've dived into the GWT world a couple of months ago and find it quite interesting.
I'm currently developing a web application which is to be used internally and so we need to resize the browser window, which can only be done by JSNI. After hitting [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573855/resizeto-in-js-gives-me-access-is-denied-error-how-to-know-if-browser-is-ready) 
regarding the JSNI I was advised to look into `jquery` and I found that it's counterpart in `GWT` is `GwtQuery`. I've tried looking on the project page and googling for tutorials but I can't seem to find a clear beginners tutorial on how to use `GwtQuery` on `GWT` but I keep find references to how it's very similar to `jquery`.
I think it's important to state that I'm not a js developer but rather a java developer who likes the idea of `GWT` and I just need to use `GWTQuery` in a very small part of my application.

Thanks in advance for any leads or links.

Ittai

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GwtQuery also goes by the name GQuery, so maybe you find more if you search for that.

At Google I/O 2009 the creator of GQuery gave a speech about GQuery, you can find the video and slides [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/events/io/2009/sessions/ProgressivelyEnhanceAjaxApps.html), maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/dodotis/gquery-a-jquery-clone-for-gwt-rivieradev-2011) I gave about gquery.

The [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted) in the project site could be useful as well.

The gquery [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gwtquery) is a good place to ask questions to developers and users.

Answer (score 1):

Here I found good article with small and simple examples:
[GWTQuery – jQuery in GWT](http://vinaytechs.blogspot.com/2009/09/gwtquery-jquery-in-gwt.html)